# Delete row numbers identified by MATCH function in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a large Master List of contacts, columns include names and phone numbers. Separately, I have a much smaller list of 'bad' phone numbers. Placing the 'bad' number column in the Master List, I used the MATCH function to identify the row numbers of 'bad' number contacts in the Master.  How can I delete the rows in the Master List represented in the MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column next to your master list and use ISERROR with MATCH to the bad list to get a true/false next to each number, with a false being a bad number and true being good. Then simply sort your column to get all falses together.

Comment: Great idea!  So if Master List of numbers is column C and 'Bad' numbers are in column F, would this work?  IFERROR(MATCH(C2,$F$1:$F2556,0),"GOOD").  The result, when copied down all rows of the Master List, should give me the row # of 'Bad' numbers and "Good" where the numbers don't match.  Filter the 'Good' and toss out the old.  Right?

Comment: @Chipnflip Yes, exactly.